# How can I solve this error when doing the fetch with svelte?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte

I have this problem, I have 2 functions: the `unlockLine` function activates a lock when an alert comes out,
and requests a password to be able to unlock it, the lock and unlock does generate it for me, but when I want to enter the password I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password').

and I don't know how to fix it.

The `getAuthorizedUserPassword` method is the one that captures the response from the API:

```
const getAuthorizedUserPassword = (AuthorizedUserPassword) => {

  return PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword(AuthorizedUserPassword)
      .then((response) => {
      Isavailablepassword = response.data.password;
      return isavailablepassword;
    })
    .catch(handleError);
};

const unlockLinewhile = () =\> {unlockLine()} //Constant that is executed at the moment of an     alert() that in turn calls another constant.


let Isavailablepassword = null;

const getAuthorizedUserPassword = (AuthorizedUserPassword) =\> {
return PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword(AuthorizedUserPassword)
.then((response) =\> {
Isavailablepassword = response.data.password;
return isavailablepassword;
})
.catch(handleError);
console.log(isavailablepassword);
};

const unlockLine = () => {
         PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(1,lineCode) //Bloqueamos toda la linea
         let imputpassword = prompt("Linea Bloqueada \n Ingresa la contraseña del supervisor", ""); //Entrada de contraseña
         getAuthorizedUserPassword(imputpassword)
         .then((response) => {
           if(response){
             PackagingApi.SetStationBlocked(0, lineCode);
           } else{
             alert("Contraseña Incorrecta \n Ingresa la contraseña Correcta para desbloquear");
             unlockLine();
           }
         });};
```

This is my function in JS to do the get

```
export const PackagingApi = (function (apiUrl) {
 apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5183';
 return {
            getAuthorizedUserPassword : async (AuthorizedUserPassword) =>
     HttpRequest.get(`${apiUrl}/api/Auth/${AuthorizedUserPassword}`),         }; });
```

This is what the API gives me with Postman:

> {     "data": {         "password": true     } }

I need that when it is true it is activated in the first IF and when it is false it enters the Else.

I need help to solve the problem described with Svelte.

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing how you have implemented the `getAuthorizedPassword()` method, but I'm guessing that you need to `JSON.parse(response)` in order to access `data` and then `password`

Comment: Sorry, I thought I posted it, but it's already added

Comment: If `PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword` is issuing a plain `fetch` request, then the body of the response is not directly accessible. You will need to do `const data = await response.json()` to get the body data and parse it's JSON value.

Comment: thanks friend, I think that was what was missing.

Comment: I'll provide a proper answer that you can accept then :-)

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your answer helped me a lot and the information you provide me is very valuable.
Here I published an answer of how the functional example turned out at the end but I will factor it with your answer since I see it as more correct.
thanks for your time.
[Code](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582707/como-puedo-obtener-la-respuesta-de-una-api-en-svelte/582760?noredirect=1#comment1031112_582760)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword` is issuing a plain fetch, it means that the response object does not provide access to the body's data. Instead, you need to request this data with one of the following methods:

- `text()`: For plain text
- `json()`: For JSON-formatted responses
- etc

You can view all the methods in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body).

This means that, in your particular case, the only thing you need to do is as follows:

```js
PackagingApi.getAuthorizedUserPassword(AuthorizedUserPassword)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    return data.password;
  })
  .catch(handleError);
```

Of course you can manipulate the Promises any way that suits you.

Bear in mind that if your returned data is not a properly-formatted JSON string, it will also make the request to fail.